# Which go concurrency pattern should I use for the following use case?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I'm having two `go routines`.

- **NewFileEntryCheck()**
- **UploadFromQueueToCloud()**

`go NewFileEntryCheck()`

This function will take a `fsnotify.Watcher()` as argument and it will watch for any file change in the specified directory inside an infinite loop.

If there is any new `file CREATE` event occurs, it will add the filename to the `Queue`

`go UploadFromQueueToCloud()`

This go routine should take the filename from the `Queue` read the file from the path and upload it to cloud.

Now, my question is, How can I make the `UploadFromQueueToCloud()` function to get value from the Queue and upload it to cloud?

Since the `NewFileEntryCheck()` function will continuously check for new files and add it to the queue, the length of the Queue is not fixed. I can't loop through the `len(Queue)` and receive data through the channel.

Is there any other approach to achieve this?

Comment: Is `Queue` a channel? You are doing things concurrently, you act on the new values as you receive them, there is no reason to try and read the length of the work queue.

Comment: @JimB No. Queue is not a channel. I just tried to put all the files to the Queue and tried to iterate through it and push each file to the cloud.

Comment: Go has channels for communication and synchronization between goroutines. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a common example of pub-sub model. You have one publisher `(NewFileEntryCheck)` and one subscriber `(UploadFromQueueToCloud)`. Because this can be modelled in the form of Pub-Sub model, you should make the design similarly.

There is already a comment that you might have received from @jimb asking that if the `Queue` is a channel. Well there is a reason for it. It's because golang channel behaves just like a queue. So one solution is definitely to model it using a channel.

Using channel, you can put the task/file name from one go routine. From another go routine `UploadFromQueueToCloud`, you can consume that channel and process the data asynchronously.

Here is the sample code

```
func UploadFromQueueToCloud(channel *chan string, exit *chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
           case file := <- channel:
               // Upload the cloud..
               // Other business logics
           case exit := <- exit:
               break;
        }
    }
}

func NewFileEntryCheck(notifier *fsnotify.Watcher) {
   channel := make(chan string)
   exit := make(chan bool)
   for {
        if (some breaking condition) {
             exit <- true;
             break;
        }
        // Check for the file notifier
        // If file CREATE happened,
        // get the file name into FileName
        channel <- FileName;
        go UploadFromQueueToCloud(channel, exit)
   }
}
```

**Note: You can increase the throughput by changing the channel into a buffered channel.**

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My case is:

```
func main() {
    allFileCheck := make(chan bool)
    fileUpload := make(chan string)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go NewFileEntryCheck(ctx, fileUpload, allFileCheck)

L:
    for {
        select {
        case file := <- fileUpload:
            go UploadFromQueueToCloud(ctx, file)
        case <-allFileCheck:
            fmt.Println("done")
            break L
        case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
            cancel()
        }
    }
}

func UploadFromQueueToCloud(ctx context.Context, file string) {
    fmt.Printf("Upload file %v\n", file)
}

func NewFileEntryCheck(ctx context.Context, fileUpload chan string, allFileCheck chan bool) {
    fmt.Println("Check file")
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fileUpload <- "name " + strconv.Itoa(i)
    }
    allFileCheck <- true
}
```